¿Por qué cuando cambio de página la pantalla no vuelve a la parte superior?
Cuando scrolleo en una página de mi sitio web de ReactJS y cambio a otra, en lugar de mostrarse al principio de la misma se muestra en la posición en que quedó la página anterior. Es decir, el scrolling se está produciendo en todas las páginas a la vez. Se trata de un sitio web muy sencillo que apenas estoy empezando a desarrollar. Alguien tiene alguna idea de cuál podría ser el problema?
Adjunto los dos componentes que manejan el cambio de página:
Mi componente principal es así:
import './App.css';
import './components/Carrusel/Carrusel.css'; 
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar/NavBar';
import Inicio from './components/Inicio/Inicio';
import Departamentos from './components/Departamentos/Departamentos';
import Ubicacion from './components/Ubicacion/Ubicacion';
import Contacto from './components/Contacto/Contacto';
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer';


function App() {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Esta función flecha maneja el evento de desplazamiento
    const handleScroll = () => {
      // Obtiene la cantidad de desplazamiento vertical de la página
      const scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      const triggerPoint = 80; // Punto de desplazamiento que activa el cambio de visibilidad del NavBar
  
      console.log("Scroll Top:", scrollTop); // Agregar esta línea para depurar
  
      // Si el desplazamiento es mayor que el punto de activación
      if (scrollTop > triggerPoint) {
        setIsVisible(true); // Establece isVisible en true para mostrar el NavBar
      } else { // Si el desplazamiento es menor que el punto de activación
        setIsVisible(false); // Establece isVisible en false para ocultar el NavBar
      }
    };
  
    // Agrega un event listener para el evento de desplazamiento
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  
    // Limpia el event listener cuando el componente se desmonta
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, []); // El array vacío [] asegura que el efecto se ejecute solo una vez, equivalente a componentDidMount
  

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <NavBar isVisible={isVisible} />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Inicio />} />
          <Route path="/departamentos" element={<Departamentos />} />
          <Route path="/ubicacion" element={<Ubicacion />} />
          <Route path="/contacto" element={<Contacto />} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;

Y mi componente navbar asi:
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './NavBar.css';

const NavBar = ({ isVisible }) => {
  return (
    <nav className={`NavBar ${isVisible ? 'fixed' : ''}`}>
      <h2>Puerto Bueno</h2>
      <ul className="nav justify-content-end">
        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link to="/" className="nav-link">Inicio</Link>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link to="/departamentos" className="nav-link">Departamentos</Link>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link to="/ubicacion" className="nav-link">Ubicación</Link>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link to="/contacto" className="nav-link">Contacto</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default NavBar;


Ok entonces lo que se busca es que al regresar se vea la pagina desde el inicio y en este momento el problema es que se regresa y mantiene la posición de la pagina anterior. Y como se supone que el usuario regresa a la pagina anterior, con el botón back del explorador web o con el componente Link?

En realidad no es al regresar, sino al cambiar de una pagina a otra pagina. Por ej: Estoy en Inicio, scrolleo hacia abajo y cuando selecciono Contacto en la barra de navegación, la pagina Contacto se muestra en la posición en que quedó la pantalla en la página anterior.

El problema puede ser debido a que se esta mutando el estado de window y document para offset y scroll dentro del efecto, además el efecto solo corre una vez, puede que el document scroll que se modifico dentro del efecto se quede como un valor establecido entre navegación, se tiene que reactivar ese estado para regresarlo al inicio. Puedes agregar una bandera de estado al efecto en el array de dependencias, con eso el efecto se puede ejecutar mas de una vez y reactivar el estado del scrollY
